# Two identical particles with spin $s$. What is the spin of its corresponding "center-of-mass" and "relative" particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Consider a system of two identical quantum particles with spin $s$ and mass $m$. Using center-of-mass coordinates one obtains an equivalent system given by a particle of mass $2m$ and one of mass $m/2$. Can we talk about the $\textit{spin}$ of these two new fictitious particles? What can we say?